# Runtime Error in C (CodeChef)

Tags: c, runtime-error

I am solving a problem on [CodeChef](http://codechef.com). The problem link is this:: http://www.codechef.com/problems/POINTS

In the problem, we take the coordinates in a 2D plane as an input from the user and then travel from the point with least x-coordinate and maximum y-coordinate to the maximum x-coordinate and least y-coordinate and then calculate the distance traveled.

What I plan to do is, take the input of all the points from the user and then sort them using the condition given on the x and y coordinate.

This is my code::

```
#include<stdio.h>


int x[100000][2];//coordinates
int c[100000][2];

void sort(int a[][2], int low, int high);           //sorting the points
void merge(int a[][2],int low, int mid,int high);   //merge sort
int main()
{
    int t;//number of test cases
    int n;//number of points

    int i;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        printf("\n");
        scanf("%d",&n);


        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            scanf("%d %d",&x[i][0],&x[i][1]);

        sort(x,0,n-1);

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            printf("%d %d\n", x[i][0],x[i][1]);

    }
    return 0;
}

void sort(int a[][2], int low, int high)
{
    int mid;
    while(low<high)
    {
        mid=(low+high)/2;
        sort(a,low,mid);
        sort(a,mid+1,high);
        merge(a,low,mid,high);
    }
}

void merge(int a[][2],int low, int mid,int high)
{
    int i=low, j=mid+1;
    int k=low;
    while(i<=mid && j<=high)
    {
        if(a[i][0]<a[j][0])
        {
            c[k][0]=a[i][0];
            c[k][1]=a[i][1];
            i++;k++;
        }
        else if(a[i][0]>a[j][0])
        {
            c[k][0]=a[j][0];
            c[k][1]=a[j][1];
            j++;k++;
        }
        else
        {
            if(a[i][1]>a[j][1])
            {
                c[k][0]=a[i][0];
                c[k][1]=a[i][1];
                i++;k++;
            }
            else
            {
                c[k][0]=a[j][0];
                c[k][1]=a[j][1];
                j++;k++;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=low;i<=high;i++)
    {
        a[i][0]=c[i][0];
        a[i][1]=c[i][1];
    }
}
```

I thought that the array size is too big and that was what caused the runtime error, so I tried reducing the array size to 100 and then running the program, but it still causes a runtime error.
For now, in the code that I have posted I only wish to sort the coordinates.
The sorting condition is this:: (as given in the problem)

*You start at the point with the least X and greatest Y value, and end at the point with the greatest X and least Y value. The rule for movement is that you can not move to a point with a lesser X value as compared to the X value of the point you are on. Also for points having the same X value, you need to visit the point with the greatest Y value before visiting the next point with the same X value. So, if there are 2 points: (0,4 and 4,0) we would start with (0,4) - i.e. least X takes precedence over greatest Y. You need to visit every point in the plane.*

Comment: `so I tried reducing the array size to 100 and then running the program,` That is an excellent way. Next step: put a few assert() statements at strategic positions of the code. (binary search / merge programs tend to have a high affinity for off-by-one / fencepost errors)

Comment: What kind of runtime error are you getting?

Comment: @wildplasser I am not that familiar to assert() statements, I'll try read and try to implement them. But, what are off-by-one errors?

Comment: @kralyk It crashes when I run it in my system. And when I run it on ideone, it says runtime error. This is the link to ideone code: http://ideone.com/mN4LLI

Comment: @coderzz027 You have forgotten an address operator in the `scanf()` line.

Comment: BTW: your merge step tests the a[] array, but assigns to the c[] array. The a[] array is never changed (except by the `sort()` function.

Comment: @coderzz027 specific to what kralyk mentioned, `scanf("%d %d",&x[i][0],x[i][1])`. The second argument in the out-param list. Either put an `&` in front of it or simply used `scanf("%d %d",x[i],x[i]+1)`. And **enable your compiler warnings**. most modern compilers will catch a mismatched format specifier-to-argument (its not uncommon for it to happen accidentally).

Comment: @kralyk Extremely sorry for such stupid errors, I corrected them, but I still get a runtime error.  AFter I enter my pair of coordinates, it just hangs, and it doesn't give a compiler warning either. :\ Please help

Comment: @wildplasser so sorry I missed, but it still doesn't work..

Comment: @WhozCraig I enabled the compiler warnings as well but it doesnt give a warning then as well.. I use Dev C++, just in case that helps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I have identified the problems:

1. In `sort()`, replace `while` with `if`. There is no reason for a loop there - you do that through recursion
2. The loop conditions in `merge()` are not right. If either `i` or `j` runs out of bounds, the rest of the other merge slice is not merged into `c`. I recommend iterating over `k`, since you need to iterate over the whole target range anyway. Note that while iterating over `k` you need to check if `i` or `j` are out of bounds - if so, you simply copy over elements from the other slice. I used short-circuit evaluation to do this, that is, the bounds-checking statement goes *before* the `||` operator, this is important, otherwise invalid memory could be accessed! (Feel free to ask for further explanation if needed)

This is the code after applying the fixes above:

```
void sort(int a[][2], int low, int high)
{
    int mid;

    if(low < high)
    {
        mid=(low+high)/2;
        sort(a,low,mid);
        sort(a,mid+1,high);
        merge(a,low,mid,high);
    }
}

void merge(int a[][2],int low, int mid, int high)
{
    int i = low,
            j = mid + 1,
            k = low;

    for (k = low; k <= high; k++)
    {
        if((j > high) || (a[i][0] < a[j][0]))
        {
            c[k][0]=a[i][0];
            c[k][1]=a[i][1];
            i++;
        }
        else if((i > mid) || (a[i][0] > a[j][0]))
        {
            c[k][0]=a[j][0];
            c[k][1]=a[j][1];
            j++;
        }
        else  // Neither i nor j are out of bounds and the 0 element is equal
        {
            if(a[i][1] > a[j][1])
            {
                c[k][0] = a[i][0];
                c[k][1] = a[i][1];
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                c[k][0] = a[j][0];
                c[k][1] = a[j][1];
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i = low; i <= high; i++)
    {
        a[i][0] = c[i][0];
        a[i][1] = c[i][1];
    }
}
```

I believe the code above does what you wanted.

Some general advice: You might want to use a simple struct for storing the coordinates. The code would become much easier to read - a code that is easier to read is also easier to debug. Also, global variables should generally be avoided if possible.

Comment: @kralyk- Hi! Sorry for posting this so late, but the code that you wrote for me fails the test case when the values entered are (0,0)(1,10)(1,5)(2,2). And I guess the reason for this is the short circuit method that you used. If `i` exceeds `mid` before `j`, it enters into the range of`j`. I haven't tried dry running the code, I'll try dry running and then post.

Comment: @coderzz027 Yeah, that's true, I overlooked that. I trust that you'll be able to fix it though :)

Comment: yepp.. I just added all the points that you mentioned into the code that I had written. Thanks though :)